# Find all matching pattern in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to get all substrings that matching a specific pattern from a larger string,

I have a string like that :

```
string = "{\huge \centering \bf{RAPPORT JOURNALIER \\ ***bouee*** \\ \formatDate{***day***}{***month***}{***year***}} \\ \small generated on~\today~at~\currenttime \par}"
```

and I want to get in a list all the elements between the triple stars ***, with that string I should get : `['bouee', 'day', 'month', 'year']`.

I could easily do that with a loop on that string, but I'm sure there is a more elegant way to do it using the regex module, but I'm not familiar with it, and I'm sure it's a very simple question that could be answered quicker on a forum than with me searching to understand that module : ) (even though I will definitely learn how to use it, it seems like a super useful module)

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the "re" module for this.

```py
import re

re.findall('\*{3}(.+?)\*{3}', string)
```

Here, we tell it to match substrings that consist of three asterisks, any number of any characters, then three more asterisks. Then, we use parenthesis to mark the inside characters as our "capturing group," so  `re.findall` returns only those.

Do note that the problem is not particularly well-defined. For instance, if you see `***word***word***word***`, it's unclear whether that should be interpreted as. In general, getting more advanced behavior with these types of problems can be difficult or impossible.